# pip2: ImportError: cannot import name RequirementParseError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I can't get pip2 to work.

I need pip2, because I need to use an older tensorflow version which is not supported by python3 pip. When trying to run `pip2 install` I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import RequirementParseError, parse_requirements
ImportError: cannot import name RequirementParseError
```

I uninstalled pip2 and reinstalled it. Also did the same for pip(3). But this didn't change a thing. I could not find anything useful on this error message and feel a bit helpless. Any ideas?

**update** forgot to mention, that I use archlinux. I installed it with `pacman -S python2-pip`

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @jordanm please see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Did you try installing packages using virtualenv ? pacman ? or using only pip ?
Which version of tensorflow are you trying to install ?

You can try install libraries using a recent pip2 version + virtualenv using the following commands:

```sh
pacman -S python2 python2-pip python-virtualenv

virtualenv -p python2 py2
. py2/bin/activate

pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install tensorflow ipython
```

You may also try uninstall python2 first and reinstall it from scratch:

```sh
pacman -Rs python2 python2-pip
```

Comment: Your first solution works, thank you! Using pip2 in this virtualenv works. The global installed pip from AUR is of course still broken.

Comment: When in doubt virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243950) suggests that the problem might be due to a version of setuptools installed in ~/.local . Maybe you can check that.

> Nevermind, setuptools was installed in my ~/.local directory for some
> reason, superceding the system install, I removed that and pip2 runs
> fine now.

Comment: That said that he has uninstalled the setuptools completely.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/984868/error-in-installing-sudo-pip-install-v-protobuf-3-0-0a2

The library is different but the error is the same.